# I need to make a column show values for # of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

"Display the number of majors associated with each undergraduate program. Only include programs that have between 2 and 10 majors"

```
SELECT prg_field AS "College", prg_name AS "Number of Majors"
FROM program 
WHERE prg_type = 'U'
```

My "Number of Majors" column is coming up as the major name, how do I change that to a value that relates to the prg_field column for College?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the number of distinct prg_name per College.  If that is correct, you can get the distinct set of College/Majors and then count the Majors per College as follows:

```
;WITH distSets as (
SELECT DISTINCT prg_field as 'College', prg_name as 'Number of Majors'
)

Select
    College
    ,COUNT(*) over (partition by College) as 'Count of Majors'
From distSets
```

There is probably another way to format this if you can't use a CTE.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT prg_field AS "College",
       COUNT( prg_name ) AS "Number of Majors"
FROM   program 
WHERE  prg_type = 'U'
GROUP BY prg_field
HAVING COUNT( prg_name ) BETWEEN 2 AND 10;
```

If there are duplicate `prg_name`s then use `COUNT( DISTINCT prg_name )` instead of `COUNT( prg_name )` top and bottom.

Comment: Yes! This worked. I couldn't remember the COUNT function. Thank you!

Comment: @Deniz If this, or another answer, has solved your issue then you can accept the answer (using the check mark below the voting buttons next to the answer) to indicate that the question is closed. If it has not answered your question then you can post a comment detailing the outstanding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a derived table subquery:

```
SELECT t1.prg_field AS "College", Count(*) As "Number Of Distinct Majors"
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT prg_field, prg_name
   FROM program 
   WHERE prg_type = 'U') t1
GROUP BY t1.prg_field
HAVING Count(*) BETWEEN 2 AND 10
```